# php var_dump(1) returns string(4)

Tags: php

I am parsing a text file using PHP and one of the lines contains simple numeric characters.
However, I came across a file that for some reason contains other "hidden" characters as part of this number.

I came upon this thread [php var_dump(); result php string(4) "1"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19311062/php-var-dump-result-php-string4-1) which hints that there might be multibyte characters but there is no solution.

Debugging

```
echo 'line:' . $line . '<br/><br/>';
var_dump($line);
var_dump(ord($line).'|'.ord('1').'|');
var_dump(chr(ord($line)));
```

Here's the output

```
line:﻿1
string(4) "﻿1" string(7) "239|49|" string(1) "�"
```

Is there a good PHP solution that would help eliminate random junk characters in a string?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP Multibyte String Functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/661832/php-multibyte-string-functions)